# Passing variable to html page using Python Django

Tags: python, html, django, variables

I am creating a site using python and django. I have 2 models, Action and Image:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Action name", max_length=50)
    keywords = models.CharField("Keywords", max_length=50)
    object = models.CharField("Object", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    uploadDate = models.DateField("Date", default=get_current_date)
    UploadedBy = models.CharField("UploadedBy", max_length=50, default="")

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, default="") 
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
```

I have created a combined form which allows users to create one action and add an image. 
Now I am trying to make a form which users can upload an image only, relating to an action, following on from the current page they are viewing the action.

Below shows the html template for ActionDetails:

```
<ul>
<li><h3> Name: </h3> {{ action.name }} </li>
<li><h3> Keywords: </h3> {{ action.keywords }} </li>
<li><h3>Uploadedby: </h3> {{ action.UploadedBy }}</li>
{% if action.object %} 
<li><h3>Object:</h3> {{ action.object }}</li>
{% endif %}
</ul>

<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="img">Add Image &raquo;</a></p>

{% if image.image %} 
<p><h3>Image:</h3><img src= "/static/app/{{image.image}}" width='300'/></p>
{% endif %}
```

I would like that once the form opens (btn 'Add Image') is clicked, the action.id is passed to the ImageForm page.

views.py:

```
def addimg(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = ImageForm;
        return render(request,'app/createForm.html', { 'form':form })
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/actions')
        else: 
            form = ImageForm;
            return render(request, 'app/createForm.html', { 'form':form })
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: try using a Django form and some input methods of bootstrap, for example `<input id="inputFile" multiple="" type="file">` it's very easy for select a file in computer and upload it to specific folder in your project ( site )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking about how to pass a value in a link, which is a basic and fundamental part of Django which is well covered in the tutorial - you may want to go back and follow that again.

Firstly, you need to define a URL which captures the value:

```
url(r'img/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.addimg, name='addimg'),
```

then you need to accept it in your view:

```
def addimg(request, pk):
    ...
```

and use it to generate the link in the template:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url "addimg" action.pk %}">Add Image &raquo;</a></p>
```